# Oracle 12c to 11g

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I designed a windows form application that connects to oracle 12c server.
Everything was great until I discovered that the client has a 32 bit operating system, and oracle c can only be installed on 64 bit operating systems.

I have been trying for a week to adapt my application to work with oracle 11g since this version can be installed in my client's computer, and it is becoming a hopeless task.
ODBC for oracle 11g does not have Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll included, and also Oracle.DataAccess cannot read Boolean datatypes from the stored procedures that I am using.
I either have to modify all my procedures, and try to fix all the issues related to  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll or start by developing a new application using oracle 11g.
I installed windows 7 32-bit on a virtual machine and had been working on it, started by a very small version of my application, and it I working, but requiring too much time !

- Is there a faster way or solution to make my application compatible with oracle 11g ?
- Is really oracle 11g more suitable for weak and limited computer than oracle 12c ? (In case I managed to convince the client to install a 64bit operating system and re-install all the programs he is using) : Client has 2GB of RAM

## Update :

I installed the packed as instructed, and the application is now running. The only problem is that I am having an error when adding a parameter of type Boolean, the error is : 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType' does not contain a definition for Boolean

this is the code I am using to call the procedure :

```
tring constr = "DATA SOURCE=localhost;PASSWORD=kidzclubadministration;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=C##KidzClub";
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);   
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
con.Open();

cmd.CommandText = "get_admin_pass";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.Add("pass", OracleDbType.NVarchar2);
cmd.Parameters["pass"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
cmd.Parameters["pass"].Value = password;

cmd.Parameters.Add("done", OracleDbType.Boolean);
cmd.Parameters["done"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

the exact error sentence is :

```
Error   2   'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType' does not contain a definition for 'Boolean' C:\Users\Jad-HP\Desktop\Windows Application\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form5.cs  44  53  WindowsFormsApplication1
```

I went to OracleDbType definition, and could not find a definition for Boolean :

```
#region Assembly Oracle.DataAccess.dll, v2.111.7.20
// C:\app\Jad-HP\product\11.1.0\client_2\ODP.NET\bin\2.x\Oracle.DataAccess.dll
#endregion

using System;

namespace Oracle.DataAccess.Client
{
public enum OracleDbType
{
    BFile = 101,
    Blob = 102,
    Byte = 103,
    Char = 104,
    Clob = 105,
    Date = 106,
    Decimal = 107,
    Double = 108,
    Long = 109,
    LongRaw = 110,
    Int16 = 111,
    Int32 = 112,
    Int64 = 113,
    IntervalDS = 114,
    IntervalYM = 115,
    NClob = 116,
    NChar = 117,
    NVarchar2 = 119,
    Raw = 120,
    RefCursor = 121,
    Single = 122,
    TimeStamp = 123,
    TimeStampLTZ = 124,
    TimeStampTZ = 125,
    Varchar2 = 126,
    XmlType = 127,
    Array = 128,
    Object = 129,
    Ref = 130,
    BinaryDouble = 132,
    BinaryFloat = 133,
}
}
```

Although when going to that same definition in Visual studio where I am developing with oracle 12c, I have a definition for Boolean :

```
#region Assembly Oracle.DataAccess.dll, v4.121.1.0
// D:\app\Jad-HP\product\12.1.0\client_2\ODP.NET\bin\4\Oracle.DataAccess.dll
#endregion

using System;

namespace Oracle.DataAccess.Client
{
public enum OracleDbType
{
    BFile = 101,
    Blob = 102,
    Byte = 103,
    Char = 104,
    Clob = 105,
    Date = 106,
    Decimal = 107,
    Double = 108,
    Long = 109,
    LongRaw = 110,
    Int16 = 111,
    Int32 = 112,
    Int64 = 113,
    IntervalDS = 114,
    IntervalYM = 115,
    NClob = 116,
    NChar = 117,
    NVarchar2 = 119,
    Raw = 120,
    RefCursor = 121,
    Single = 122,
    TimeStamp = 123,
    TimeStampLTZ = 124,
    TimeStampTZ = 125,
    Varchar2 = 126,
    XmlType = 127,
    Array = 128,
    Object = 129,
    Ref = 130,
    BinaryDouble = 132,
    BinaryFloat = 133,
    Boolean = 134,
}
}
```

Is there a solution other then modifying all the procedures and replacing all Boolean variables ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Oracle Managed Data Access DLL to talk to an 11g database.  I have an application in production doing that right now.

I can't say I've yet installed an Oracle 12c database, nor even a 12c Oracle client, so I can't say whether either requires a 32-bit client.  I got the Oracle Managed Data Access DLL from NuGet, and I avoid the need for an Oracle client by using a [connect descriptor](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E10927_01/featConnecting.htm#sthref135) rather than a TNS name in the connection string.  I don't see why you can't use this approach with your app.

Comment: I did not use this approach because I did not know that there is such, since I do not have much of experience in these matters, this is my first application using oracle. I only have tried using Oracle.ManagedDataAcces.dll from my workspace ( the one that came with odbc for oracle 12c) but it did not work since it was not compatible with oracle 11g. I went to [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=odp.net) and found lots of Oracle.ManagedDataAccess,dll versions to download. How to choose the compatible version for oracle 11g in a 32-bit environment ?

Comment: I used [this one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/odp.net.managed/).  When you say Oracle Managed Data Access 'was not compatible with oracle 11g', what do you mean?  Did you get an error message, and if so, what?

Comment: Hi, I installed the packed as instructed, and the application is now running. The only problem is that I am having an error when adding a parameter of type Boolean, the error is : 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType' does not contain a definition for Boolean. I will modify my first question with the new results

Comment: Booleans in Oracle have always had a bit of a low status.  For one thing, they're not SQL types.  Generally they are best avoided if you want to call them from anywhere outside of PL/SQL.  I don't know of a simple way to adjust your calls to stored procedures to work with booleans.  I don't want to tell you that your only option is to replace all of the boolean stored procedure parameters with something else, but I fear that you may have no alternative.

Comment: Okkay, I will use then a wrapper procedure , that has char as variables instead of Booleans, and call the old procedure in it, that is the fastest solution I found, in that way old procedure will still be functional on oracle 12c systems. Thank you for your responses. Best regards

Comment: @ElGaGa: glad to hear you've come up with a workable approach.  I'm sorry there isn't a quicker solution to your problem.  As you probably know, working with Oracle databases can be very frustrating at times.